# Another way to say "you're not to blame" without the word blame?

Tags: idiom-request

Another way to say "you're not to blame" without the word blame?

The only expression I can think of is "You're not at fault", but is there another way of saying this? I am pretty sure there's an expression that sounds really good, but I don't remember what it might have been. I used wiktionary, but couldn't find anything.

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=blame+insource%3Aenglish+idioms&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're innocent
- You're not responsible
- You're not at fault
- It's not your fault
- You're not guilty
- Don't feel guilty
- You're not culpable